# How to replace one alphabet by same alphabet and new line character in Java regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Hi I want to replace a string e.g.

`<foo/><boo/><woo/>`

in such a way so that it becomes -

`<foo/>
<boo/>
<woo/>`

If I find `<[A-z]` and replace by `\n<` then the first character is gone. How to retain that too?

P.S I am trying to play in Notepad++ now but finally it will go into Java code.

Comment: **Warning:Do not use `[A-z]` in your regexes.**  To match any uppercase or lowercase ASCII letter, use `[A-Za-z]` or set the *Ignore Case* flag and use `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`.  `[A-z]` can also match several punctuation characters whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
(?<=>)(?=<)
```

use the above regex and then replace the matched boundary with `\n` character.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/13)

```
String s = "<foo/><boo/><woo/>";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=>)(?=<)", "\n"));
```

**Output:**

```
<foo/>
<boo/>
<woo/>
```

**OR**

```
String s = "<foo/><boo/><woo/>";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?!^)(<[A-Za-z])", "\n$1"));
```

This regex would work on notepad++ also.

Answer (score 2):

Simply capture what you want.

```
(<[^>]*>)
```

Replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/14

EDIT:

If you do not want an extra newline at the end try

```
(<[^>]*>)(?!$)
```

Replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/15

Comment: but it creates an extra newline character at the last.

Comment: @AvinashRaj an extra newline at end doesnt make this an incorrect answer.This is not an IPS exam,We are here to help.An downvotes without comment is the worst thing IMHO